# Mac Wiki for managing information

Tags: mac, wiki

I have seen several questions regarding use of wikis for managing development related information and thought I would try it out as I want to document the process of a system i need to install.

Is there a recommended personal wiki app for mac?

Comment: are you looking for something that would run locally on your mac or on a webserver??

Comment: locally on my mac

Comment: Should this be on Super User? (Not really a programming question even if it's for "development related information")

Answer (score 2):

Along with TiddlyWiki as David mentioned, VoodooPad is also pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_wiki):

> A personal wiki is a wiki maintained primarily for personal use.
>   Personal wikis allow people to organize information on their desktop
>   or mobile computing devices in a manner similar to community wikis,
>   but without the need for collaboration by multiple users. Personal
>   wiki software can be broadly divided into multi-user wiki software
>   with personal editions, and those wiki applications that are designed
>   only for single users, not depending on a database engine and a web
>   server. The first class includes wiki applications such as MoinMoin or
>   TWiki, as these can be installed for standalone use as well. This may
>   require installing additional software, for example a web server, a
>   database management system, or a WAMP/LAMP software bundle.
>   Nevertheless, this does not mean the wiki must be accessible to
>   outside users. Some personal wikis are public but password-protected,
>   running either on their own webservers or hosted by third parties.
>   This has the advantage that the personal space can be accessed and
>   edited from any computer or PDA with a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

[TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) is pretty good. It consists of a single html file which gets updated through javascript to include what you added or edited. It's very easy to back-up, copy, or remove. Excellent to put on a USB-drive and it works on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/) myself. A Mac has Apache built in and DokuWiki is very easy to set up. You can also use it on a [USB drive](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-05/16-dokuwiki_on_a_stick_2008-05-05).

Answer (score 1):

For a work wide wiki we have [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) set up on our Mac OS X Server, while I use [VoodooPad](http://www.flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/) to store the more sensitive information and information that doesn't need to be shared with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

What is your editor of choice? If it happens to be vim, there's a [vimwiki](http://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/) plugin.

Also, [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) has built-in wiki.